# Average length of parallel lines in a triangle.

Tags: geometry, average

My problem is that I need to find the average length $L$ of $i$ infinite parallel lines within a triangle, which can be at any angle $\theta$, between $0$ and $\pi$.
Known are the co-ordinates of the corners of the triangle (labelled $x_1y_1$, $x_2y_2$, $x_3y_3$).

[image]

I have a method, which finds the area of the shape, and dividing by the perpendicular length between the extremes of these parallel lines, but this method isn't ideal as it gives three different equations, depending on theta (at least the way I have solved it).

Comment: It seems that the average length will be the area of the triangle divided by the "extent of the triangle in the perpendicular direction". In this case, for example, that extent would be the distance between the parallel lines going through $(x_2,y_2)$ and through $(x_3,y_3)$.

Comment: You might expect there to be three different equations depending on which edge meets all the parallel lines: in your illustration the edge from $(x_2,y_2)$ to $(x_3,y_3)$ but if $\theta$ were slightly larger then the edge from $(x_1,y_1)$ to $(x_3,y_3)$  and if $theta$ were almost $\pi$ then the remaining edge